# Prevent writing to database on unit tests - .NET MVC / Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am attempting to write unit tests for an existing .NET MVC 4.5 web application that uses Entity Framework. I'd like to test that a `bool` method returns `true`/`false` as expected; however the method under test writes to a database log.

Unfortunately, these tests throw the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No connection string named 'xxxDbContext' could be found in the application config file.

I do not want the database to be modified, and I'm struggling to find a sample of how to mock the `DbContext in this example.

How can I test **only** the boolean results without actually writing to the database? In the sample below, `Logger.Log()` adds a row to the database, and I don't want the actual database being modified during unit tests.

Here are simplified examples of what the code looks like:

### Test method

```
[TestMethod]
public void LocalFileCompare_File2IsNull_ReturnsFalse()
{
    var t = new tManager(new tSet());
    FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\TempFile.txt");
    FileInfo file2 = null;

    var result = transferSet.LocalFileCompare(file1, file2);
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

### Method under test

```
public bool LocalFileCompare(FileInfo file1, FileInfo file2)
{
    if (file1 == null || file2 == null)
    {
        Logger.Log("LocalFileCompare: One or both files are null.");
        return false;
    }
    if (file1.FullName != file2.FullName)
    {
        Logger.Log($"LocalFileCompare - file names don't match.");
        return false;
    }
    if (file1.Length != file2.Length)
    {
        Logger.Log($"LocalFileCompare - file sizes don't match.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is `Logger`?

Comment: either inject your marked up logger or use a compiler macro to write a different method for logger

Comment: @Steve The "inject" approach is what I explained in my answer.

Comment: You could use Moq to mock your db - its pretty good -> https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/08/07/intro-mocking-moq/

Comment: @DanielLoudon Mocking the db is for integration tests. Unit tests should all be run in memory with no external dependencies.

Comment: Mocking is primarily used in unit testing. An object under test may have dependencies on other (complex) objects. To isolate the behavior of the object you want to replace the other objects by mocks that simulate the behavior of the real objects. This is useful if the real objects are impractical to incorporate into the unit test. - can't post source because I'm on mobile

Comment: If you can't or don't want to change your existing code you have to resort to a mocking framework that is capable of mocking static method calls. Typemock or Telerik Just Mock are (commercial) frameworks that support mocking static classes. Microsoft Fakes is free but a bit dated.

Comment: @DanielLoudon You are correct, I misunderstood what you meant. I'm leaving up my original comment so your reply still has context.

Comment: It's ok - I didn't know what it was a couple of month ago

Comment: Presuming `Logger` is under your control them use Dependency Injection to inject a mock `DbContext` during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LocalFileCompare()` method depends on the `Logger` class (a.k.a. it is "tightly coupled"). Because the implementation of `Logger` writes to the database, you cannot avoid writing to the database when you call `LocalFileCompare()` unless you remove the dependency. You do that by instead making the method depend on an interface, make the `Logger` class implement that interface, and then "inject" it into the `LocalFileCompare()` method.

This will allow you to easily create a mock logger class by simply implementing the interface and having the implementation not write to the database.

Step 1: Create an `ILogger` interface

Step 2: Change your `Logger` class to implement `ILogger`

Step 3: Change the signature of your `LocalFileCompare()` method to include an `ILogger` parameter

Step 4: Add the `Logger` instance to all calls to `LocalFileCompare()` method

Step 5: Update your test(s) with a mocked `ILogger` implementation

```
// Step 1
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

// Step 2
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    void Log(string message)
    {
        // Implementation here
    }
}

// Step 3
public bool LocalFileCompare(FileInfo file1, FileInfo file2, ILogger logger)
{
    if (file1 == null || file2 == null)
    {
        logger.Log("LocalFileCompare: One or both files are null.");
        return false;
    }
    if (file1.FullName != file2.FullName)
    {
        logger.Log($"LocalFileCompare - file names don't match.");
        return false;
    }
    if (file1.Length != file2.Length)
    {
        logger.Log($"LocalFileCompare - file sizes don't match.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// Step 4
// Update your calls to LocalFileCompare()

// Step 5
// Put this somewhere in the Test project
public class MockLogger : ILogger
{
    void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}

// In your test class
ILogger mockLogger;

// In your Test Setup method
mockLogger = new MockLogger();

[TestMethod]
public void LocalFileCompare_File2IsNull_ReturnsFalse()
{
    var t = new tManager(new tSet());
    FileInfo file1 = new FileInfo(@"C:\Temp\TempFile.txt");
    FileInfo file2 = null;

    var result = transferSet.LocalFileCompare(file1, file2, mockLogger);
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick and dirty solution without having to use dependency injection you could use `Preprocessor`

something like

```
public void Log()
{
#if UnitTest
//Log to file
#else
//Log to db
#endif 
}
```

and then add a new configuration name `UnitTest`. Switch to that config and go to project property -> Build -> Conditional compilation symbols -> add `UnitTest` in

Comment: Yeah, do that and you're gonna have a bad time sooner or later :)

Comment: @Bartosz that's why its a quick and dirty solution. ideal if you are only doing it on small scale.

Comment: Well, I'm not saying you're not warning the OP :) It's such a dirty hack to a proper design principle that it should be illegal though:)